# Can I read out the "folder path" I am currently using in Outlook?

Tags: vba, outlook

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MailSpeichern()

'       //Variablen
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim Item As Object
Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim Items As Outlook.Items
Dim lngCount As Long

Set Item = Application.ActiveExplorer
Set Item = Item.Selection(1)
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set Inbox = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("address@email.org").Folders("Posteingang")
Set Items = Inbox.Items
Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("temp")

Item.Close olSave
Item.Move SubFolder
Debug.Print Item.Subject


Set Items = Inbox.Folders("temp").Items
    
For lngCount = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set Item = Items(lngCount)
    Debug.Print Item.Subject
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
'          // Move Mail Item to Inbox
        Item.Move Inbox
    End If
Next lngCount


End Sub
```

I made a script to save and move an Email to another folder and back. Need it for syncing a shared mailbox faster. It works on the email currently open in the explorer. I'd like to know if there is a way to read out the "folder structure" I am currently in. So it does work in any folder without manually adjusting the path in code.

Comment: `Item` will have a `Parent` property representing the folder it's in...

Comment: You have used the `Application` object in the single line of code twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Folder.FolderPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.folderpath) property returns a string that indicates the path of the current folder.

You can get the folder where the item is located by using the [Parent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.parent) property.

```
Dim parentFolder as Outlook.Folder 
Set Item = Item.Selection(1)
Set parentFolder = Item.Parent

Debug.Print parentFolder.FolderPath
```

Also, I've noticed that you create a new Outlook `Application` instance in the code:

```
Set Item = Application.ActiveExplorer
Set Item = Item.Selection(1)
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

If the code is run from the Outlook VBA environment you need to use the `Application` property instead. The `CreateObject` function is used to create a new Outlook `Application` when you need to automate Outlook from external applications like Word, Excel and etc. So, what you could basically do is initialize the `olApp` object:

```
Set Item = Application.ActiveExplorer
Set Item = Item.Selection(1)
Set olApp = Application
```

Or just use the `Application` property where required without using any other object references.

In the code the same object reference is used for keeping different types of objects:

```
Set Item = Application.ActiveExplorer
Set Item = Item.Selection(1)
```

I'd recommend using a strongly typed object references and have separate object references for each kind of objects in the code. Just to compare:

```
Dim explorer as Outlook.Explorer
Dim selectedItem as Object

Set explorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
Set selectedItem = Item.Selection(1)
```

The reason why you still need to declare the selected item as `Object` is that the `Selection` object may contain different kind of items - appointments, documents, mail items and etc.

Comment: I used `Set Inbox = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder` to get the result I need. Thank you a lot for your tips. This is my first VBA Makro and I was just throwing bits and pieces together until it worked. I edited my Question because I did stumble upon a new problem. Maybe you can help me there as well.

Comment: You have used the `Application` object in the single line of code twice.